# Setting defaults when .getIntent().getExtras() is null

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to pull user input from a couple `EditText` fields into another activity. In particular, I'd like to utilize team names input by the user in another activity of the app.

So, taking input from here:

[image]

and using it here:

[image]

As seen in the photo above, I've been successful in implementing this when the user enters in a couple team names, which I'm handling with `getIntent().getExtras()`.

However, if the user clicks the "Start Scorekeeper" button without entering in any team names, I get the following:

[image]

However, I'd like to set default team names of "Team A" and "Team B".

I've tried to accomplish this with the following (which hasn't worked):

**TeamSelector.java**:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ScoreKeeper.class);

    final EditText teamAInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.team_a_input);
    String teamAName = teamAInput.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("teamA", teamAName);

    final EditText teamBInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.team_b_input);
    String teamBName = teamBInput.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("teamB", teamBName);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Then creating a conditional as I pick up the intent.

**ScoreKeeper.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score_keeper);

    Bundle teamNames = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(teamNames==null){
        final TextView teamAText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teamAText);
        teamAText.setText(getString(R.string.team_a_name));

        final TextView teamBText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teamBText);
        teamBText.setText(getString(R.string.team_b_name));
    }
    else {
        String teamA = teamNames.getString("teamA");
        final TextView teamAText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teamAText);
        teamAText.setText(teamA);

        String teamB = teamNames.getString("teamB");
        final TextView teamBText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teamBText);
        teamBText.setText(teamB);
    }
}
```

I've also tried coding default strings in the XML, which hasn't been effective (only one team included for brevity):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="@string/team_a_name"
    android:id="@+id/teamAText"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Is there a way to effectively set a default when `.getIntent().getExtras()` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A String from EditText is never null. It can be empty but not null.

A simple check like this would work

```
teamAText.setText(!teamA.isEmpty() ? teamA : "Team A");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ScoreKeeper.class);

    final EditText teamAInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.team_a_input);
    String teamAName = teamAInput.getText().toString();
    if(teamAName.trim().equals("")) teamAName="Team A";
    i.putExtra("teamA", teamAName);

    final EditText teamBInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.team_b_input);
    String teamBName = teamBInput.getText().toString();
    if(teamBName.trim().equals("")) teamBName="Team B";
    i.putExtra("teamB", teamBName);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The strings will not be null, nor will the intent necessarily. The strings will be zero length strings, which you can use `String.isEmpty()` to test against.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```
teamAText.setText(getString(R.string.team_a_name));
teamBText.setText(getString(R.string.team_b_name));
```

to this:

```
teamAText.setText(R.string.team_a_name);
teamBText.setText(R.string.team_b_name);
```

It is because [getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) needs an `int` as parameter and your `R.string.team_a_name` and `R.string.team_b_name` are `Strings` so you don't have to convert it again (Further that they are not `ints`).

I expect it will be helpful for you!